# Why is Elm Build not working? Gives wrong path

Tags: build, elm

Elm 0.19
`create-elm-app myapp` and `elm-app start` shows the logo and `"Your Elm App is working!"`
Good.

The README recommends then elm-app build. Doing that I get a build folder with an `index.html`.
Opening shows nothing. Crome Console errors.

```
src="/static/js/vendors~main.3ca81432.chunk.js" path wrong?
src="static/js/vendors~main.3ca81432.chunk.js" shows the text but not pic (wrong path..)
```

Am I doing wrong or is this an error from Elm-side?

Alternative: `elm make Main.elm —output=main.html`
not nice to put all the js stuff in the html.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid tools like `create-elm-app`. In my experience they just make customization and errors like these harder to figure out.

`elm make` will output a js file if you specify the output as a js file instead of an html file:

```
elm make Main.elm —output=main.js
```

You can then create your own html file where you start Elm by running `Elm.Main.init`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script>
      Elm.Main.init({node: document.getElementById("app")});
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

`create-elm-app` can really help you get something decent up and running quickly – I like it.

There are several places where paths are referenced and the first time you build you'll need to tailor things to what you're trying to achieve.

## TL;DR: You need to configure your local path, and references in `Main.elm`

Create a new file called  `elmapp.config.js`.

Paste the following into it:

```
/*
More config information here:
https://github.com/halfzebra/create-elm-app/blob/master/template/README.md#overriding-webpack-config
*/

module.exports = {
    homepage: "./" //required to normalise path
}
```

Open your `src/Main.elm`, find the `---- VIEW ----` block and tweak it as follows:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ img [ src "logo.svg" ] []
        , h1 [] [ text "Your Elm App is working!" ]
        , img [ src "./static/images/logo.svg" ] []
        ]
```

Removing the `/` from the path is a good idea as `main.js` instantiates this asset incorrectly. This could be changed to `./`, which is interpreted as an absolute path (relative to the environment). Both syntax will work the same.

If you clone the `logo.svg` into a new folder called: `static` inside an `images` folder, you can reference the original `[ img [ src "logo.svg" ] []` from the root directory and `, img [ src "./static/images/logo.svg" ] []` with a relative path anywhere.

Now `elm-app build` will point to `./logo.svg` and `./static/images/logo.svg`, as expected from `main.js`.

---

Going into a bit more detail, the following should help if you're beginning any search for any inconsistencies:

In `README.md` there are some key thoughts on the path variable:

```
For the project to build, these files must exist with exact filenames:

* `public/index.html` is the page template;
* `public/favicon.ico` is the icon you see in the browser tab;
* `src/index.js` is the JavaScript entry point.
```

You can also specify where you want to `elm-app build` deploy path:

```
## Changing the base path of the assets in the HTML

By default, assets will be linked from the HTML to the root url. For example `/css/style.css`.

If you deploy to a path that is not the root, you can change the `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable to properly reference your assets in the compiled assets. For example: `PUBLIC_URL=./ elm-app build`.
```

### Where to make quick-start changes:

`index.html` contains `%PUBLIC_URL%/` probably in the 
`<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">` and icon meta.

In `src/index.js` you'll notice: `./` this means root and current object:

```
import './main.css';
import { Elm } from './Main.elm';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

Elm.Main.init({
  node: document.getElementById('root')
});

registerServiceWorker();
```

In `elm.json` you'll see `"source-directories"` – this might be useful if you plan on adding packages without polluting your working directory:

```
   {
    "type": "application",
    "source-directories": [
        "src"
    ],
    "elm-version": "0.19.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "direct": {
            "elm/browser": "1.0.0",
            "elm/core": "1.0.0",
            "elm/html": "1.0.0",
            "elm/svg": "1.0.1",
            "elm/url": "1.0.0",
            "justgage/tachyons-elm": "4.1.1"
        },
        "indirect": {
            "elm/json": "1.0.0",
            "elm/time": "1.0.0",
            "elm/virtual-dom": "1.0.0"
        }
    },
    "test-dependencies": {
        "direct": {
            "elm-explorations/test": "1.0.0"
        },
        "indirect": {
            "elm/random": "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

In `public/manifest.json` you'll see `"start_url": "./index.html"` and `"src": "favicon.ico"` too:

```
  `{
  "short_name": "Elm App",
  "name": "Create Elm App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. It's one of those SO questions that's too frustrating not to answer.

Comment: Thanks so far..Still I am struggling with the picture (logo.svg) I cant get it displayed after building..
I have created an asserts folder in public. It is copied in build assets, 
index.js: import logoPath from '../public/assets/logo.svg';
I have a url: http://localhost:4000/assets/logo.svg. But no pic..
What is the best practice für pictures?

Comment: Views differ on "best practice" so you should make the decision to best fit your project. The example has been updated to include referencing assets from an absolute path. I hope that helps.